# Send small amounts to PayPal API

Tags: api, paypal, floating-point, floating-point-precision, fixed-point

I'm using the PayPal API to handle payments on my website. A product has the following prices :

- exclusive of tax : 0.083€
- vat rate : 20%
- all taxes included : 0.10€

In the API, we have to send the items of an order with the exclusive of tax unit price and the vat rate.

Here is my request :

```
{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency": "EUR",
        "total": "99.60",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "83.00",
          "tax": "16.60"
        }
      },
      "item_list": {
        "items": [
          {
            "quantity": "1000",
            "name": "My product",
            "price": "0.08",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "sku": "1-20140407123511492"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, since PayPal accepts only prices with a maximum of 2 decimals, there is an error in the final calculation (0.003€ multiplied by the quantity).

In the end, I have the following error :

```
{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"transactions","issue":"Item amount must add up to specified amount subtotal (or total if amount details not specified)"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"132eaa3f14cce"}
```

So, how can we handle small prices with the PayPal API ?
Thanks.